# How to write a typings file for exported javascript object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a javascript file file that looks like this:

```js
// methodHelpers.js
export default {
   refetchData: function() {
      // do some data refetching
   }
};
```

Now I would like to have a typings file (methodHelpers.d.ts) that would allow me to get code editing completions for the methods on the object I am importing.

I have tried:

```js
// methodHelpers.d.ts
export interface methodHelpers {
  refetchData(): void;
}
```

But the completions are still missing.

Comment: Did you give that type to your object? `let obj: methodHelpers;`

Comment: I want it to be applied automatically because of the matching filenames. Also this is a javascript project so I can't use normal types like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `export default` that interface instead of just `export`'ing it because it is a default export in the original file.